# why do I lose access to php variables when I render a new page

Tags: php, require

I have a render function that looks like:

```
function render($template, $values = array()){

   // if template exists, render it
   if (file_exists("../views/$template")){

      // extract variables into local scope
      extract($values);

      // render header_form
      require("../views/header_form.php");

      // render template
      require("../views/$template");

      // render footer
      require("../views/footer_form.php");

   }else{

      // else err
      trigger_error("Invalid template: $template", E_USER_ERROR);

   }
}
```

Suppose I have a script crew.php that looks like this:

```
<?php

    require('../includes/config.php');
        $values=[];           

        $today = new DateTime();

        render('crew_form.php',$values);

?>
```

Why don't I have access to $today in crew_form.php? For instance, if crew_form.php was:

```
<?php

    echo $today;
?>
```

When you use require doesn't that just add the script to the existing code?  Is it because of local scope of the function render()?

Comment: you need to set it into `$values['today'] = $today` (then you need to use `->format(...)` you cant simply echo an object).. basically your passing `$values` to a function, and extract.. extracts what's in `$values`, so the keys are the variables

Comment: reread the question, you are not understanding what is being asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to `$today` because you're **out of scope**. The variable is defined outside a function, and is not available inside it -- and `render()` is a function.

You can obviate the problem with the `use` keyword, or by abusing the `global` directive, but a better way to avoid polluting the scope would be passing the variables explicitly and reading them with [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Which is exactly what your code was attempting doing, using `$values`. But you need to put `$today` inside `$values` and pass it to `render()`:

```
$values['today'] = $today;
```

Now, a variable called `$today` will be available in crew-form.php, *but it will not be the same `$today`* even if it will start as a copy of the same value. You can see it better like this:

```
$values['today2'] = $today;
```

Inside crew-form.php, `$today2` will exist, `$today` will not, because the latter is "out of scope".

Changes to the extracted values will be lost upon exit from `render` (you can use EXTR_REFS but that adds complications).

Comment: you mean inside crew_form.php don't you?

Comment: `crew_form.php` remains inchanged

Comment: wasn't my upvote as your answer was bonkers

Comment: @DCR okay, tried to salvage the answer as I can't delete an accepted answer.

Comment: no problem, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is sometimes called 'shared nothing'. In a single HTTP request, *everything* gets built up from scratch, and after the request is complete all memory is released.

If you want information to carry over between requests, you need a storage mechanism such as a database. This is by design and always has been the case for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that my hunch is correct.  If $today was created in the render function we can indeed print it out in crew_form.php.